# EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'storeApps' in [apps in AppWidgetsComponent@8:28]

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Ok, I have a problem that a lot of people appear to be having a problem with, but none of the solutions on stackoverflow or GitHub appear to help.

I am getting an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'storeApps' in [apps in AppWidgetsComponent@8:28]
```

which I believe is being cause by the ngFor:

```
<div class="container app-widgets">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offet-1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="#widget of apps"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding component definition is:

```
import { Component, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common';
import { AppWidgetComponent } from '../appwidget/appwidget.component';
import { StoreApp } from '../../models';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-widgets',
    template: require('./appwidgets.component.html'),
    styles: [require('../../../sass/appwidgets.scss').toString()],
    directives: [AppWidgetComponent]
})
export class AppWidgetsComponent {
    @Input() apps: Array<StoreApp>;
}
```

and I am using the `app-widgets` component like this:

```
<app-widgets apps=storeApps></app-widgets>
```

I am setting `storeApps` in the corresponding component definition:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html'),
    styles: [require('../../../sass/home.scss').toString()],
    directives: [AppWidgetsComponent, RecommendedRecentComponent]
})
export class HomeComponent {
    private storeApps: Array<StoreApp>;

    constructor(private _appsService: AppsService) {
    }

    recentSelected() {
        this._appsService.getRecentApps()
            .subscribe(
                storeApps => {
                    this.storeApps = storeApps;
                    this.storeApps.forEach(element => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(element));
                        console.log();
                    })
                },
                (error: any) => AppComponent.generalError(error.status)
            );
    }
}
```

The `AppService.getRecentApps()` method looks like this:

```
public getRecentApps() {
    return this.http.get(`${appSettings.apiRoot}resources/recent`)
        .map(res => <StoreApp[]> res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

What puzzles me is why it is complaining about `storeApps`, which appears in the app component, and not the `apps` which is appearing in the `app-widgets` component.

Any ideas people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
<app-widgets apps=storeApps></app-widgets>
```

is equivalent to this expression (it sets the attribute value to the string `"storeApps"`):

```
<app-widgets [attr.apps]="'storeApps'"></app-widgets>
```

You should use:

```
<app-widgets [apps]="storeApps"></app-widgets>
```

Comment: Actually I don't think "is a shorthand for" is true. `<app-widgets apps=storeApps></app-widgets>` is just passed to the browser to be added to the DOM while `<app-widgets [attr.apps]="'storeApps'"></app-widgets>` is template binding processed by Angular. True, the result is the same, but I wouldn't say it's a shorthand.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Updated the answer. Thanks (;

Comment: I am out and about at the moment and can't test your suggestion, but will do so in n a couple weeks f hours. Muchly appreciation.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, `apps="storeApps"` is a shorthand for `[apps]=" 'storeApps' "` according to [Savkin's blog post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax) (see section Passing Constants).  Sasxa, note that the shorthand binds to the `apps` property, not the HTML attribute, so it is not equivalent to `[attr.apps]=" '...' "` but rather `[apps]=" '...' "`.  (Which is why I really don't like this shorthand syntax, since it looks like attribute binding.)

Comment: @MarkRajcok Can you give some pointer where in the blog post this is mentioned? I'm pretty sure `apps="storeApps"` "binds" to an attribute. Actually it doesn't *bind* because it's not handled by Angular. If there is an `@Input()` with the same name then it also becomes a property of course.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I did mention it: "see section Passing Constants".

Comment: @MarkRajcok Sorry, missed that. When you inspect `<foo-cmp>` in https://plnkr.co/edit/wm4TrO?p=preview in the browser console  you'll see that the first has an attribute `someattr` while the 2nd doesn't. Therefore I wouldn't consider one as substitute of the other.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, very interesting.  So `someattr="some"` is equivalent to attribute AND property binding.  I.e., it is equivalent to (a shorthand for) `someattr="some" [someattr]=" 'some' "` or `[attr.someattr]="some" [someattr]=" 'some' "`.  Weird.  I like this even less now.  So Sasxa, you and I were both half right. :)

Comment: @MarkRajcok I would interpret it this way: `someattr="some"` is basically non-Angular HTML (it isn't subject to any Angular action and just passed to the browser and inserted into the DOM as is), but when a component has an `@Input()` matching the name, then the property is bound to the attribute.

Comment: I had a typo above.  Correction/summary: if `someattr` is an input property, then `someattr="constant string"` is equivalent to (a shorthand for) `someattr="constant string" [someattr]=" 'constant string' "` or `[attr.someattr]=" 'constant string' " [someattr]=" 'constant string' "`.